# Redirect user to new link without their knowledge

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I wanted implement this using `.htaccess` file. In my page I have a link to `link1`. When user clicks, I want them to show another page `link2`. But I want browser url to continue showing `link1`.

I have found many similar questions here. But I am unable to implement them because of my lack of knowledge about `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: Then tell us what exactly is unclear with the answers you found. What sense would it make otherwise for us to write the 74538365837th answer to this question? Also, which passage of the documentation or the rewriting module is so unclear? Sorry, but we cannot help if you don't tell us your issue.

Comment: How exactly `redirection` in `server` and  `url change` in `client browser` implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Root/.htaccess` file

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^link1\.php/?$ /link2.php [L,NC]
```

This will internally redirect the `/link1.php` **to** `/link2.php` , and your browser will remain at the  `/link1.php` .

Answer (score 0):

You simply don't provide the `[R]` (redirect) option.

```
RewriteRule ^link1$ link2 [L,NC]
```

If you want to redirect silently to another domain, you can use the `[P]` option if you have `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` installed.

```
RewriteRule ^link1$ http://example.com/link2 [L,P]
```

Comment: I have tried this. but url is changing to link2. Whether this will work even if `link2` is an external link like `http://example.com`?

Comment: You can't rewrite to a different domain without the URL changing.

Comment: @BitwiseCreative That is not true, actually you _can_. You just have to use the proxy module embedded in the rewriting module.

Comment: There is nothing more to say, really. This is well documented: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p.